# Facebook-style multiple image upload

Tags: file-upload

Facebook has the ability to select multiple images in the file browser in its upload feature.

Can anyone explain how this is achieved?

I'd like to do something similar in jquery without the use of a flash widget.

Comment: You can also try [plupload](http://www.plupload.com/), although there are some bugs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [HTML5 File API](http://www.w3.org/TR/FileAPI/) enables you to do it natively. Basically you add the `multiple="multiple"` attribute to the file upload control:

```
<input multiple="multiple" type="file" ... />
```

Disadvantage: Only runs in modern browsers like Firefox, Chrome, Safari. IE, even version 9 does not support this multiple upload.

Otherwise, you have to rely on some Flash or Java upload component.

*(Edit: Changed to `multiple="multiple"`, thanks to [Ms2ger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/33466/ms2ger))*

Comment: I guess I should read up on HTML5. I don't need to support IE so this'll be fine. Thanks!

Comment: What happens in IE? I assume it will just fall back to a normal single file upload right?

Comment: Yes, in IE it behaves just like a normal single-file upload control. See this Wikipedia article for an overview who implements the API: http://bit.ly/eYmgDm

Comment: This is wrong. multiple="true" is invalid. The correct code would be <input multiple type="file" ... > or <input multiple="" type="file" ... >. As you want images, you would preferably use <input multiple type="file" accept="image/*" ... >, though. (At least in Firefox 4, this will limit the file picker to image files.) Also, this has nothing to do with the File API; it is part of HTML: <http://www.whatwg.org/html/#file-upload-state>.

Comment: Thanks, @Ms2ger. I just tried it (http://www.zeta-uploader.com - The site I'm using this by myself) It succeeded with the latest Firefox (3.6.x), Safari, Google Chrome, when using `multiple="true"`. Can you tell me a Browser that fails? I'll then check and correct.

Comment: I didn't say it doesn't work, I said it is invalid. All browsers that support multiple="" also support multiple="true", but the problematic point is that they also support multiple="false" to mean the exact same thing. Using multiple="true" is just confusing. See the spec: <http://www.whatwg.org/html/#boolean-attributes>.

Comment: Thank you, @Ms2ger. I'll change it accordingly to `multiple="multiple"`.

Answer (score 0):

The best and easiest jQuery-based multiupload scripts (IMHO):

http://www.uploadify.com/
http://www.uploadify.com/demos/

free and open source

Answer (score -1):

Instructions on how to include jQuery File Upload with Rails setup https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Rails-setup-for-V5/35cca0e5e21b5c8fb29b89e9675314907ac1a464

(note: this question was originally answered 3 years ago, the above link may have inaccurate instructions for recent versions of the referred gems/libraries, but may be easy for someone to follow and fix whatever have changed).