# How internet behemoths like facebook handle the delivery of the photo content?

Tags: php, facebook, photos

As they have lots of traffic I am wondering how they handle (or you can make an assumption on how they do this) delivery (loads and uploads) of their main asset - photos?

Are they keeping everything in the database? Do they encode with something like "Base64 Decode and Encode" and keep the content in the database? Or maybe they just somehow storing only the links in the database to the images.

As you can see I am having a hard time presuming so maybe you will be able to help me.

Comment: Sane people don't store images in a database - whether base64 encoded, or even as blobs - sane people use the filesystem: in the case of Facebook, I'd suggest they use a pretty substantial CDN

Comment: @MarkBaker Yep, Facebook uses Akamai.

Comment: The reason why they can serve pictures so quickly to you is because they - like google - have lots and lots of mirrors all around the globe. If you and I enter facebook.com it's not likely we'll even bee redirected to the same server, because the DNS records are different throughout the internet. As to how they are actually stored on the servers, I haven't the slightest idea :D

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4641766/facebook-style-multiple-image-upload

Comment: Read for yourself : https://www.facebook.com/note.php?note_id=76191543919